# Change function from click event to window load

Tags: javascript, postmessage

I am trying to change `postMessage` from sending a message to an iframe on click to sending it on page load.

On the parent page:

```
var el = document.getElementById('button');

var getFontFamily = function(){

    for(var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < document.styleSheets[i].rules.length; j++){

            if(document.styleSheets[i].rules[j].style.fontFamily){
                return document.styleSheets[i].rules[j].style.fontFamily;
            }
        }
    }

    return 'not-found';
};

window.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var data = getFontFamily();

    window.frames[0].postMessage(data, 'http://localhost:3000');

    console.log('Message sent -->');
});
```

The iframe page has the following to receive the `postMessage` event.

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(e){
        document.body.style.fontFamily = e.data;

        console.log('<---Message received');
    }, false);
```

How can I change this to load the css from the parent to the child on page load and not on click?

Current working example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/nzjfn6u4/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code from this:

```
window.addEventListener('click', function(){
```

to this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nzjfn6u4/2/

Comment: Not sure how I missed that. Thanks!